# SQL statement to get book titles, names of the customer and show the titles of the books that were not ordered

Tags: sql

My question is: Make a statement to get book titles, names of the customer and also show the titles of the books that were not ordered. It mean that we need to show all the title of the book and the name that customer ordered. Also, if the book(s) were not orderd, we need to show the title of these book(s) with NULL value of the name of customer(s)

I need to use traditional join with the WHERE clause (not ANSI join with the JOIN keyword).

Here is my statement right now:

```
SELECT b.title, c.firstname, c.lastname
  FROM books b, orderitems oi, orders o, customers c
  WHERE b.isbn = oi.isbn
  AND oi.order# = o.order#
  AND o.customer# = c.customer#
UNION
SELECT b.title
  FROM books b
  WHERE b.isbn NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT isbn FROM orderitems);
```

The result return is: query block has an incorrect number of result columns.

It seems the code makes sense but I don't know what I need to fix.

The structure of my database:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: You need to use a JOIN instead. A UNION will not work at all here. And the error is caused because your first SELECT returns 3 columns, but your second only returns one. How do you think that would work in a UNION, which merges the results of two statements into a single table?

Comment: I just can use the WHERE and AND instead JOIN. That's why I try to use UNION or something like that.

Comment: No, you can't do what you're asking witha UNION. A UNION **will not work** for what you're asking. Why can you just use only WHERE and AND?

Comment: Oh, I see it, I will review again for not using UNION. Use only WHERE and AND is required.

Answer (score 1):

"The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns
The columns must also have similar data types
The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order"

(reference https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

So you are receiving the error because all rules for UNION are violated in your query.

Since you're planning on not using 'JOIN' for whatever reason, you can join tables this way:

```
Select c.CustomerNo, c.first, c.last, o.OrderNo, o.CustomerNo, o.shipment
from Customers c, Orders o
where c.CustomerNo = o.CustomerNo;
```

However, using JOIN would be the best way to write the query.